# Numeric integration for two variables and a list of parameters?

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, numerical-integration, calculus

In the MATLAB documentation, they have an example for numeric integration for a single variable with one parameter `c` as:

```
fun = @(x,c) 1./(x.^3-2*x-c);
q = integral(@(x)fun(x,5),0,2)
```

What if I want to do numeric integration with two variables and maybe two parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do integration with two variables you need to use [`integral2`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral2.html).

An example with two variables:

```
fun = @(x,y) 1./( sqrt(x + y) .* (1 + x + y).^2 );
ymax = @(x) 1 - x;
q = integral2(fun,0,1,0,ymax)

q =
    0.2854
```

If you want several parameters, and two variables do:

```
fun = @(x,y,c,d) c./(sqrt(x + d*y) .* (1 + x + y).^2);
ymax = @(x) 1 - x;
q = integral2(@(x,y) fun(x,y,3,4),0,1,0,ymax)

q =
0.5708
```

Or simply:

```
c = 3; d = 4;
fun = @(x,y) c./( sqrt(x + d*y) .* (1 + x + y).^2 )
ymax = @(x) 1 - x;
q = integral2(fun,0,1,0,ymax)

q = 
    0.5708
```